# Google API ListPermissions nextPageToken problem

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm having trouble passing the nextPageToken to the next iteration of a dowhile loop. Its specifically a problem with the drive.permissions.list api. The error is "The specified page token has expired, and can no longer be used". When I breakpoint this at the "while" line I can see nextPageToken is updated to the nextPageToken. However, it still throws the error on the next loop. I was thinking this might be a problem with the async function itself and how/when the code is executed but I get the same results if I remove async/await. I have an almost identical function for drive.drives.list and it works perfectly. Any help would be appreciated. Thx

**List Permissions function. Will not pass nextPageToken to next dowhile iteration**

```
async function listPermissions(auth, gdrive) {
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });

let nextPageToken = null;
do {
   await drive.permissions.list({
        fileId: gdrive,
        pageSize: 100,
        pageToken: nextPageToken,
        supportsAllDrives: true,
        fields: "nextPageToken, permissions(id, type, role)",
        useDomainAdminAccess: true
    })
        .then((response) => {
            const permissions = JSON.stringify(response.data.permissions);
            console.log(`Permissions Detail: ${permissions}`)
            nextPageToken = response.data.nextPageToken;
            console.log(`NextPageToken: ${nextPageToken}`)
              //do work here
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(`The API returned an error: ${err}`) })
} while (nextPageToken !== null);

}
```

**List Drives function works fine**

```
async function listDrives(auth) {
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });

let nextPageToken = null;
do {
    await drive.drives.list({
        pageSize: 100,
        pageToken: nextPageToken,
        fields: "nextPageToken, drives(id, name)",
        useDomainAdminAccess: true
    })
        .then((response) => {
            const drives = response.data.drives;
            nextPageToken = response.data.nextPageToken;
            //do work here
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(`The API returned an error: ${err}`) })
} while (nextPageToken !== null);
}
```

Comment: Try to retrieve only the id, I doubt it but it could be that you are retrieving too much data.

Comment: Hey @Jescanellas , thanks for the suggestion but I get the same error if I retrieve the id only.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. I'm currently flagging drives with >99 permissions to review manually later but would love to get the nextPageToken working for this. Thx in advance.